# Slow Query - Help with Optimization

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization

Hey guys. This is a follow-on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944932/problems-with-monthname-on-mysql-5):

After getting the right data and making some tweaks based on requests from business, I've now got this mini-beast on my hands. This query *should* return the total number of new jobseeker registrations and the number of new uploaded CV's:

```
SELECT COUNT(j.jobseeker_id) as new_registrations,
(
    SELECT 
      COUNT(c.cv_id)
    FROM 
      tb_cv as c, tb_jobseeker, tb_industry
    WHERE
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.created_at) >= '1241125200'
    AND 
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.created_at) <= '1243717200'
    AND 
      tb_jobseeker.industry_id = tb_industry.industry_id
) 
AS uploaded_cvs
FROM 
  tb_jobseeker as j, tb_industry as i
WHERE
  j.created_at BETWEEN '2009-05-01' AND '2009-05-31'
AND
  i.industry_id = j.industry_id
GROUP BY i.description, MONTH(j.created_at)
```

Notes:
- The two values in the UNIX TIMESTAMP functions are passed in as parameters from the report module in our backend.

Every time I run it, MySQL chokes and lingers silently into the ether of the Interweb.

Help is appreciated.

Update: Hey guys. Thanks a lot for all the thoughtful and helpful comments. I'm only 2 weeks into my role here, so I'm still learning the schema. So, this query is somewhere between a thumbsuck and an educated guess. Will start to answer all your questions now.

Comment: You'll have to provide some information about the tables involved in this query... which columns have indexes, etc.? ... Also, could you format the query a little friendlier to the eyes?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You will need to give us the schema and the indexes you're using if you want help on optimization.

Comment: What's this cv_id? A full table? Also, in the subquery, tb_cv is not joined/linked to tb_jobseeker and tb_industry. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @Midiane: I suspect the query should return the number of jobseeker registrations and CVs created per industry per month? Is that correct?

Comment: @Tomalak yes, you're right. Sorry guys, got called into two long meetings.

Comment: Then I'll update my query accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tb_cv is not connected to the other tables in the sub-query. I guess this is the root cause for the slow query. It causes generation of a Cartesian product, yielding a lot more rows than you probably need.

Other than that I'd say you need indexes on `tb_jobseeker.created_at`, `tb_cv.created_at` and `tb_industry.industry_id`, and you might want to get rid of the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` calls in the sub-query since they prevent use of an index. Use `BETWEEN` and the actual field values instead.

Here is my attempt at understanding your query and writing a better version. I guess you want to get the count of new jobseeker registrations and new uploaded CVs per month per industry:

```
SELECT 
  i.industry_id,
  i.description, 
  MONTH(j.created_at)            AS month_created,
  YEAR(j.created_at)             AS year_created,
  COUNT(DISTINCT j.jobseeker_id) AS new_registrations,
  COUNT(cv.cv_id)                AS uploaded_cvs
FROM 
  tb_cv AS cv
  INNER JOIN tb_jobseeker AS j ON j.jobseeker_id = cv.jobseeker_id
  INNER JOIN tb_industry  AS i ON i.industry_id  = j.industry_id
WHERE
  j.created_at BETWEEN '2009-05-01' AND '2009-05-31'
  AND cv.created_at BETWEEN '2009-05-01' AND '2009-05-31'
GROUP BY 
  i.industry_id,
  i.description, 
  MONTH(j.created_at),
  YEAR(j.created_at)
```

A few things I noticed while writing the query:

- you GROUP BY values you don't output in the end. Why? (*I've added the grouped field to the output list.*)
- you JOIN three tables in the sub-query while only ever using values from one of them. Why? I don't see what it would be good for, other than filtering out CV records that don't have a jobseeker or an industry attached — which I find hard to imagine. (*I've removed the entire sub-query and used a simple `COUNT` instead.*)
- Your sub-query returns the same value every time. Did you maybe mean to correlate it in some way, to the industry maybe?.
- The sub-query runs once for every record in a grouped query without being wrapped in an aggregate function.

Comment: +1 Indeed there is a cartesian product on tb_cv and tb_jobseeker

Comment: I must admit that I'm not strong on SQL and I used parts of other queries used in the system to get to this... *sheepish*

Comment: hey tomalak, i just tried your query. it works perfectly! thanks. and it's much easier to read and not as complex as my poor attempt. i stripped out a few fields I don't need. Thanks a lot, seriously.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost it may be worth moving the 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' conversions to the other side of the equation (that is, perform a reverse function on the literal timestamp values at the other side of the >= and <=). That'll avoid the inner query having to perform the conversions for every record, rather than once for the query.

Also, why does the `uploaded_cvs` query not have any where clause linking it to the outer query? Am I missing something here?